# Invalid JSON Primitive When Passing With Ajax

Tags: json, ajax

I'm trying to create a json object and pass it as a parameter using Ajax. Here's the js

```
        var model = {
            "Name": "test",
            "Location": "Place",
            "Interests": ["Code", "Coffee"]
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/CT01211/test",
            contentType: "application/json'",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                message: model
              }
            });
```

Here's the c#:

```
        public class ModelTest
        {
            public string Name { set; get; }
            public string Location { set; get; }
            System.Collections.Generic.List<string> Interests { set; get; }
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult test (ModelTest message)
        {
            return Json(message);
        }
```

Everything time I try I get the error: "Invalid JSON primitive".

I've tried JSON.stringify(model)

I've tried single quotes instead of double when building the model variable

I've tried changing the contentType and dataType

I've tried not having quotes around the properties:

```
var model = {
            Name: "test",
            Location: "Place",
            Interests: ["Code", "Coffee"]
        };
```

No matter what, I get the error. 
Little help?